# How can I get generics in javadoc code block displayed?

Tags: java, generics, javadoc

I have a javadoc code block where I want to write a code sample that includes generics like this:

```
public interface SomeInterface <T> { }
public interface SomeInterface extends SomeOtherInterface<T> { }
```

Here is my javadoc block:

```
  /**
   * Get the Generic Type T of a Type (Class/Interface) or extended/inherited Subtype: 
   * <pre>
   * {@code
   * public interface SomeInterface <T> { }
   * public interface SomeInterface extends SomeOtherInterface<T> { }
   * }
   * </pre>
   * @param implType
   * @param parentType
   * @return
   */
  public static JClassType findGenericType(JClassType implType, JClassType parentType) { ... }
```

The javadoc output is:

```
Get the Generic Type T of a Type (Class/Interface) or extended/inherited Subtype:


 public interface SomeInterface  { }
 public interface SomeInterface extends SomeOtherInterface { }
 }

Parameters:
implType
parentType
Returns:
```

The Generic  is missing in the output.

**How can I get javadoc to display the generics correctly?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Java doc is rendered to HTML, so anything between angular brackets (`<>`) would be interpreted as an HTML tag, and won't be printed as text.
You can use `&lt;` and `&gt;` in order to render HTML `<` and `>` respectively:

```
 /**
   * Get the Generic Type T of a Type (Class/Interface) or extended/inherited Subtype: 
   * <pre>
   * {@code
   * public interface SomeInterface &lt;T&gt; { }
   * public interface SomeInterface extends SomeOtherInterface&lt;T&gt; { }
   * }
   * </pre>
   * @param implType
   * @param parentType
   * @return
   */
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaDoc uses html to render.  Therefore, if you want a left angular brace (<) and right angular brace (>) to appear in the JavaDoc, you need to use `&lt;` for a left angular brace and `&gt;` for a right angular brace.  For instance:

```
/**
* Get the Generic Type T of a Type (Class/Interface) or extended/inherited Subtype: 
* <pre>
* {@code
* public interface SomeInterface &lt;T&gt; { }
* public interface SomeInterface extends SomeOtherInterface&lt;T&gt; { }
* }
* </pre>
* @param implType
* @param parentType
* @return
*/
```

See [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you **can** place the generic  in the javadoc itself.  I know this isn't valid HTML, I assume javadoc processor has special case handling for  it.

Using your example:

`/**
 * @param <T> the type
 */
public interface SomeInterface <T> { }`

Source: https://binkley.blogspot.com/2006/08/javadoc-generic-type-parameters.html

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
/**
 * Explain something...
 * <pre>
 * public interface SomeInterface &lt;T&gt; { }
 * </pre>
 */
```

This is since JavaDoc is rendered as HTML and `<>` must therefore be escaped to be properly rendered.

Edit: after clarification from the OP I changed the answer.

Comment: I want to write a code example in my JavaDoc not what you did?