# Bug in javadoc for link to bounded generic type?

Tags: java, generics, javadoc

Something a coworker of mine found:

Using Java 8, the `javadoc` for this class doesn't generate correct html:

```
public class JavadocBounds {
    /**
     * A method with a parameter of type {@link Callback}<T extends {@link ResultCode}>.
     */
    public <T extends ResultCode> void method(Callback<T> callback) {}

    static class Callback<T> {}

    static class ResultCode {}
}
```

This works fine (without the generic's bound):

```
/**
 * A method with a parameter of type {@link Callback}<{@link ResultCode}>.
 */
```

Are we getting the syntax wrong?

Is this fixed in later Java versions?

Is this relevant enough to post a bug? If so, where?

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be with the literal `<` and `>` characters, which should be escaped as `&lt;` and `&gt;`. Probably, if `<` is followed by a letter (as in the first case), it is interpreted as a HTML tag and things go wrong.

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27592872/133203)

Answer (score 0):

Javadoc is working fine. It is ignoring `<` and `>`. In order to include these signs, you have to be using `&lt;` for `<` and `&gt;` for `>` sign.